# Error when `tar` a `.zip` on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, zip, tar

I zipped a directory on my Mac OSX with the `zip` command line and `-r` option. I `scp` the `.zip`
 to a cluster operating on Linux.

If I try to decompress the `.zip` with

`tar -vxzf foo.zip`

on my machine it works. But the same command doesn't work on the cluster. I get the error

```
gzip: stdin has more than one entry--rest ignored
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `tar` command is for unpacking TAR archives, not zip files. You should either use the `unzip` command instead of `tar`:

```
unzip foo.zip
```

Or make a `tar.gz` archive on the Mac side instead of a zip file

```
tar -cvzf foo.tar.gz ....
```

which you can unpack with your existing `tar` command on the Linux side.

Comment: Sounds obvious now +1. I didn't really know what TAR archive are. Btw, why did `tar` worked on `.zip` on my Mac then? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Remi.b tar on Mac is a version of BSD tar rather than the GNU tar used on Linux distributions. [The apple Man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html) suggests Mac tar can handle zip files, but GNU tar can't (except in the limited case described in the other answer).

Answer (score 7):

This error :

```
gzip: stdin has more than one entry--rest ignored
```

Means that `tar` is trying to decompress your zip archive as if it was a gzip archive, that doesn't always work (see "[Files created by zip can be uncompressed by gzip only if they  have  a single  member  compressed with the 'deflation' method"](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?gzip) for more info).

You should use `unzip foo.zip` instead to decompress a zip archive.

Answer (score 2):

Standard GNU `tar` doesn't handle `.zip` files directly. I'm surprised MacOSX handles it.

The problem is that `tar` knows how to handle **`gzip`** files, which are **not** Info-Zip (`.zip`) format files. Info-Zip files are designed to handle both archiving and compressing, while `tar` does not. (Most `tar` implementations now will filter the `tar` file with the proper compressor/decompressor based on the command-line options.)

Use `unzip` on your cluster instead. That's the program designed to handle `.zip` files. You shouldn't need `tar` at all.